# Can I place a robots.txt file inside a subdomain and it only affect that subdomain and not the root domain?

Tags: seo, subdomain, robots.txt

Can I place a *robots.txt* file inside a subdomain and it only affect that subdomain and not the root domain?

For example:

I have `example.com` and `mysubdomain.example.com`. `mysite.com` already has a *robots.txt* that does it's own directives. Can I disallow all bots to `mysubdomain.example.com` by placing a *robots.txt* inside it's own folder and it not affect my main domain `example.com`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Whatever the web root for the subdomain is where you would put a `robots.txt` for that subdomain's contents. It will not affect the root domain and the root domain's `robots.txt` will not affect the subdomain.

Comment: Damn, beat me too it by 25secs :)

Comment: Ok perfect, thank you. So you could also put a robots.txt inside mysite.com/folder and it would only apply to items in that folder correct?

Comment: Actually, no. `robots.txt` can only be placed in the web root.